# A problem with linear operator in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $(H,(\cdot,\cdot)_H)$ and $(Q,(\cdot,\cdot)_Q)$ two Hilbert separable spaces s.t $H\subset Q$ and let $B:H\to Q$ a bounded and linear operator. Let $\sigma,\tau\in H$ two fixed elements.

My question is find $\chi$ in terms of $\sigma, \tau$ and $B$ such that

$(B(\sigma),B(\tau))_Q=(\chi,\tau)_Q$

EDIT: The relation between those inner products is

$(\sigma,\tau)_H=(\sigma,\tau)_Q+(B\sigma,B\tau)_Q$

I believe that we must use the Riesz representation theorem or the Riesz operator.

Comment: Do you remember the definition of the adjoint operator?

Comment: Yes... i get

$(B(\sigma),B(\tau))_Q=(\tau,B^*B(\sigma))_H$ but i don't get the desired equality in the inner product of $Q$

Comment: I forget an important information! 

The relation between those inner products is 

$(\sigma,\tau)_H=(\sigma,\tau)_Q+(B\sigma,B\tau)_Q$

Comment: Waitwaitwait. For $\sigma,\tau \in H$, $(\sigma,\tau)_Q$ doesn't make sense. Unless $H$ is a subset of $Q$.

Comment: Yes, $H$ is a subset of $Q$, sorry for my omissions.

Comment: I'm trying of generalice the case for $H=H(div;\Omega)=\{v\in L^2(\Omega):div(v)\in L^2(\Omega)\}\subset L^2(\Omega)$ and $Q=L^2(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I  look for the general case, if this is possible.

Comment: I'm afraid in general you can't express $(B(\sigma),B(\tau))_Q$ as $(\chi,\tau)_Q$ then. The latter is continuous in the $Q$ topology, the former in general not.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @DanielFischer, since OP is satisfied with your answer given in the comment, shy don't you post it as answer?

Answer (score 1):

In the situation Where $H\subset Q$, and the inner product on $H$ is given by

$$(\sigma,\tau)_H = (\sigma,\tau)_Q + (B(\sigma),B(\tau))_Q,$$

you can in general not express the linear form

$$\lambda \colon \tau \mapsto (B(\sigma), B(\tau))_Q$$

(change the roles of $\sigma$ and $\tau$ if your inner products are linear in the first and antilinear in the second argument) as a $Q$-inner product, since $\tau \mapsto (\chi,\tau)_Q$ is (for all $\chi$) a continuous linear form on $Q$, but $\tau \mapsto (B(\sigma),B(\tau))_Q$ is in general not continuous in the subspace topology.